# Como criar um usuario com AbstractBaseUser ou AbstractUser. (Erros de login)

Tags: python, aplicação-web, django, login

Estou tentando utilizar minha classe `Pessoa` como usuario no `models.py`.
Entretanto tentei usar `AbstractUser` e `AbstractBaseUser`. Ambos me retornam erros na parte onde tento efetuar login, testei diversas maneiras até perceber que necessito de ajuda de alguém com mais experiencia e conhecimento que eu.

Meu **models.py**:

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class Pessoa(AbstractUser):
    id_pessoa = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    cnpj = models.CharField(max_length=14, unique=True)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    senha = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False)
    ativo = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    datacadastro = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    cidade = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    uf = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'cnpj'

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'pessoa'
```

> Detalhe: estou impossbilitado de remover ou adicionar campos em
>   qualquer modelo que estou utilizando, porque eu usei `inespectdb` para
>   criar os modelos baseados no banco de dados que estou utilizando(*O
>   mesmo que já esta cheio de dados*). Qualquer alteração, **com exceções
>   de alterações básicas**, está fora de cogitação.

Abaixo meu `views.py` com a `def` que valida o login e redireciona para o `dashboard`.

```
def dash_login(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST, None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #if form.is_valid():
        username = form.data['cnpj']
        password = form.data['senha']
        user = authenticate(username=username)
        print(username)
        #p = Pessoa.objects.filter(cnpj=form.data['cnpj']).values('id_pessoa')[0]['id_pessoa']
        #login(request, user)
        print(request.user.is_authenticated)
        #return render(request, 'dashboard.html')
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

Eu utilizo print() para testar os comandos antes de sair executando, no momento quando ele chega na linha:

> `user = authenticate(username=username)`

**Ele dispara este erro:**

> File "C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 85, in _execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column pessoa.password does not
>   exist LINE 1: SELECT "pessoa"."password", "pessoa"."last_login",
>   "pessoa"....
>
> **Independente que eu ponha senha dentro do `authenticate` o erro é
>   disparado.**

**Essa foi a segunda opção:**

```
def dash_login(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST, None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(form.is_valid())
        if form.is_valid():
            cnpj = form.data['cnpj']
            print('Valido')
            print(cnpj)
            p = Pessoa.objects.filter(cnpj=cnpj).values('id_pessoa')[0]['id_pessoa']
            #print(p)
            #return redirect('dashboard', p)
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

Onde eu caio no mesmo erro, caso eu retire o `p` e use `return render(request, 'dashboard.html')` Eu estou redirecionamento sem o id do usuário, o que me gera problemas para pegar os dados dele dentro do dashboard.

Contudo ainda tenho o problema principal, essa tabela está logando no login do Django e não no login que eu criei dentro do `models.py`|`forms.py`

Erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Edit1: models.py que estou tentando integrar.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, User
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


class Pessoa(AbstractUser):
    id_pessoa = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    cnpj = models.CharField(max_length=14, unique=True)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    senha = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False)
    ativo = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    datacadastro = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    cidade = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    uf = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'cnpj'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'pessoa'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

Mensagem de erro ao dar migrate:

```
 File "C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "WITH ORDINALITY"
LINE 6:                     FROM unnest(c.conkey) WITH ORDINALITY co...
```

Erro completo https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV54h.png

O fato de eu não conseguir dar `migrate` explica o erro anterior que explica que o componente não existe na `table` do `model`.

> **Edit:** O erro foi gerado quando executei `inspectdb` e o banco estava
>   com uma versão desatualizada(*PostgreSQL*), era necessário atualizar
>   para uma versão mais nova e executar o  código novamente, para poder
>   inspecionar seu banco e criar modelos a partir dele.
>
> **Outro possível erro** é que ele te impede de dar `migrate` por esse
>   mesmo erro, e isso pode causar erros de faltas de campos no banco por
>   não poder dar `migrate`

Comment: Após criar o novo model `Pessoa` você rodou o `python manage.py makemigrations` e depois o `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Sim, já até criei backup de teste, e testei varias coiass, não sei onde estou errando.
Inclusive as coisas funcionam, SE, eu não tentar puxar alguma informação do Pessoa.objects

Comment: Eu chutaria então que você não teria adicionado a sua app Django onde o model `Pessoa` está definida lá no `INSTALLED_APPS` do `settings.py`. Esse erro que aparece é exatamente porque o Django está tentando usar uma tabela no banco de dados que ainda não existe.

Comment: @mazulo Já está lá. Na verdade eu estou tendo um erro ao dar migrate, que me impede de criar a tabela via django pra poder existir o campo.

Comment: Coloca na pergunta essa informação também, junto com a mensagem do erro completa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ola,
Tente fazer `makemigrations` e `migrate` colocancando o nome do APP

```
python manage.py makemigrations NOMEDOAPLICATIVO
python manage.py migrate NOMEDOAPLICATIVO
```

Pode ser esse o ERRO, ele não esta migrando corretamente.

Estava vendo seus códigos e não consigo o que você esta importando (quais bibliotecas) `import`

Um Exemplo que estou usando no meu sistema `model.py`:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import re

from django.db import models
from django.core import validators
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.utils.http import urlquote
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager
from django.conf import settings


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
  #codigo omitido para dimimuir o exemplo, ele será chamado no meio do User para gerenciar o User

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=15,
    help_text=_(É obrigatório. 15 caracters ou menos. Letras,numeros e@/./+/-/_ caracters'),
    validators=[validators.RegexValidator(re.compile('^[\w.@+-]+$'),
     _('Use um nome Valido.'), _('invalid'))])
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.CharField(_('birth date'),max_length=10,null=True, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
      help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'))
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(default='accounts/defaults/default1.jpg', upload_to=upload_location1) #, blank=True) # null=True)
    picresume = models.ImageField( default='accounts/defaults/default1.jpg', upload_to=upload_location2 ) #, blank=True , null=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username','birth_date'] 

    class Meta:
    #explica para o django se usa o plural
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def get_full_name(self):
        #Returna nome e sobrenome juntos 
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        #Returna nome curto.
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        #envia email , vai precisar no futuro , para resetar a senha.
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```

DICA: 
Se usar no `settings.py`

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-BR'
```

QUASE toda as palavras padrões como email,user estão na interface (site) mensagem de erro , texto de ajuda (help text) estarão em Português.

link de métodos de login 1: https://medium.com/@gabrielfgularte/custom-user-model-no-django-d9bdf2838bd8

link de 4 métodos de login 2:(esta em ingles) https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Espero que tenha ajudado. Abraço.

Comment: Olá, muito obrigado pela sua reposta explicativa, porem já acessei estes mesmos links e outros, estava me perdendo dentro de um erro que acredito já ter resolvido, mas vou explica-lo para entendimento geral.
Basicamente eu uso um banco PostgreSQL, e o mesmo estava na versao 9.3, entao atulizei ele uma vez para 0 10.6 para usar inspectdb e usar como models.py, já que não preciso cadastrar dados do zero, apenas usa-los ou inserir poucos dados. E em seguida tive erros de componentes inexistentes, pois ao dar migrate ele dava erros de versao do Postgre, logo tive que atualizar tudo e dar migrate.

Comment: Agradeço MUITO pela ajuda, e vou verificar meu código novamente para desencargo de consciência, acabei utilizando OneToOneField, mas em um futuro projeto usarei AbstractBaseUser como você utilizou de exemplo. Até então você foi a unica ajuda que tive após uma semana inteira indo atrás de ajuda sobre esse assunto e até então ninguém tinha me dado nem um norte. Então vou dar muito valor para esta resposta! Fico agradecido!